# How to compare multiple elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to compare each element in two columns.

One column of elements are with the same class name and the other column of elements are with the same id(and different names).

I can use

```
document.getElementsByClassName( "myClass" )
```

to get all the elements in the 1st column, and use

```
$("[id=myId]")
```

to get all the elements in the second column.

The question is, how to compare the value of each of them?

Comment: $('#yourId'), thats how you target id's i jquery.

Comment: This can only get one element. But I have multiple elements with this same id and I need to access all of them...

Comment: Please edit your question and add some html code to see how your columns looks like

Comment: You should never use same id, id should be unique

Comment: "*But I have multiple elements with this same id...**" - well that's your problem, then: stop using an `id` (a duplicate `id` makes the whole document invalid and murders kittens), and instead use a `class` to associate the elements. Once that's done *then* you get to [edit] the question and - probably - get answers.

Comment: Apart from that IDs need to be unique.. what do you mean you want to compare? Compare what? The HTML/text inside? And what do you want to get out of that? The difference? The part thats the same?

Answer (score 0):

how about this if you don't have the id of the first column? .each() will loop through each element of that class, we pass it an anonymous function that executes for each iteration of the loop.

```
$('.Col1Class').each(function(){
    if ($(this).val() === $('#Col2Id').val())
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        //Do other stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: using val property will treat columns as inputs

Comment: @YouneL OP specified "how to compare the value of each of them?", without any markup I can't say what his column is, it could be a column of inputs for all we know. But yeah just change .val() to .text() if not

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over elements that share the same class name and then compare them to whatever you want here is an example:

```
$('.myClass').each( function () {
    if ( $(this).text() == $('#id').text() ) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Used another approach to get this done:
get multiple elements for the parent box, and access child using find().

Answer (score -1):

```
If($('#id').val() == $('#id2').val(){
 //IF they match then do this  
} else {
//IF no match then do this code
}
```

Comment: The problem is the first column does not have id, only class. I guess I may need to loop thorough, but I don't know how to access each element.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge `$('#id1') === `$('#id1')` will return `false` (see: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5qumzjsj/), since they're different Objects, therefore comparing jQuery Objects containing different collections (`$('#id1')` and `$('#id2')`) will always evaluate to `false`.